# Dangers of using rm command with variables

Tags: bash, cron, date, rm

I am creating a crontab that compresses 15 minute clips from my security camera into one file (24 Hours Long) and then having the clips delete.

```
avimerge -o /media/jmartin/Cams/video/Full_$(date +%F --date "Yesterday") -i /media/jmartin/Cams/video/$(date +%F --date "Yesterday")* # Converts files from the past 24 hours into one .avi

rm /media/jmartin/Cams/video/$(date +%F --date "Yesterday")* # Removes old clips that have already been compressed
```

My question is What is the danger of using the $date variable. Could something possibly happen where it deletes all files in /video/? What would you recommend as a safer alternative?

Example filenames (Yes, those are spaces in the filename):

```
2016-04-25 00:00:01.avi  
2016-04-25 00:15:02.avi 
2016-04-25 00:30:02.avi  
2016-04-25 00:45:01.avi
```

Comment: Can you give a few example filenames?

Comment: @frostschutz Added to original post

Comment: a word from someone who has lost some invaluable photos in a similar situation like this: Instead of deleting files, consider acquiring some free or very inexpensive storage space and move your files there. Since they are security camera feed videos, I am pretty sure they will be obsolete in 30-60 days time period. Once every 30-60 days, go to your storage space and delete everything manually. If for nothing, just for the peace of mind in my opinion.

Comment: if possible add a constatnt prefix to your clips filename, like `clip-2016-04-25 00:00:01.avi`. That way when deleting `.../clip-$(date ...)* ` files you don't risk to erase the other files.

Comment: @Emmanuel Great idea, I will be sure to do that!

Comment: what would be safer would be to use different directories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things jump out:

1. You have no checking for failure of the substitution
2. There is a race condition if the date changes between uses of the `date` command.

You could solve them both like this:

```
#/bin/bash

# Exit if any command fails
set -e

dir='/media/jmartin/Cams/video'
day=$(date +%F --date Yesterday)

# Conbine files from the past 24 hours into a single AVI file
avimerge -o "$dir/Full_$day" -i "$dir/$day"*

# Remove old clips that have already been compressed
rm "$dir/$day"*
```

Comment: if for some reason the $dir and $day are empty, The final command would result in an `rm /*`.  on a short script it is not a problem but on longer, possibly managed by other people that can be dangerous

Comment: @Emmanuel How do you suggest I go about fixing that. That would be an absolute nightmare.

Comment: @SimplePi you could test if the vars are empty or add something constant in the path like `rm "$dir/clip-$day"*` to protect the path. Another possibility would be to test in a loop each file to see if the name matches your format.

Comment: Just for clarification, in my answer, the variables will never be empty - `dir` is set to a fixed, non-empty value, and `day` will have a value unless `date` errors (which will abort the script due to `set -e`).

Comment: @TobySpeight You can write a script that is perfect at the origin, then modify it later to add features, and do it again and again. If it don't includes some security at the rm level, you have a risk. On your script the risk is minimal because it is small but I remember a small script that deleted  `/bin/cat`  on  500 servers because of a forgotten backcote.

Answer (score 5):

The `$(date +%F --date "Yesterday")` technically isn't a variable, it's a command substitution, but that is tangential to your question. This construct could prove to be problematic if for some reason the `date` command wasn't in your `$PATH`, and thusreturned nothing - at which point it would delete everything in `/video/`. If you instead take that command substitution and assign it to a variable prior to the `avimerge` command, then use that variable in both the `avimerge` and `rm` commands, you're not only ensuring that the date string being operated on doesn't change, but you're also able to test for a zero-length variable before either command and (if you have a zero-length string) exit before doing something you don't want to.

Comment: So are you suggesting i set `DATE = /bin/date +%F --date "Yesterday"` and then run `rm /media/jmartin/Cams/video/$DATE*`

Comment: +1 for pointing out that a single date value should be generated and used for all related commands, instead of several potentially conflicting ones.

Comment: @SimplePi: yes, that is what I'm suggesting, in addition to sanity checking the value of `$DATE` after you establish it.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is always a space in your filenames, I'd include that in your command:

```
rm "$(date +%F --date "Yesterday") "* # Removes old clips
```

That should be an easy way to prevent deleting all files in the directory, as even if `date` doesn't return anything, it would only delete files starting with a space character (which hopefully do not exist).

However there are several other dangers, for example

- `avimerge` might fail in some way and you end up deleting files that haven't been merged...
- `avimerge` might take considerable time and by the time `rm` runs, yesterday is today and you end up deleting the wrong stuff...

Basically it's a bad idea to blindly trust that these command did what you wanted them to. For automated deletion, you should check and double check everything and make sure to use your variables properly.

You should put the `date` result in an actual variable, check what the variable looks like, and then use that same variable for both commands so it can't change in between.

You should check the return codes (exit codes) of the commands you call and only proceed when there is no error returned by them (or specifically handle errors you are expecting).

You should check that the merged file was created and has a realistic file size.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you get the script right and you don't run it in a weird environment, everything should be fine.

But if something breaks the expected output of `date`, all bets are off. For example, if you run this snippet with `IFS=-`, then you'll be running something like

```
rm /media/… 04 26*
```

i.e. delete files beginning with `26` in the current directory. Of course this is just due to a rookie mistake in your script: you forgot [the double quotes around the command substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).

```
rm "/media/jmartin/Cams/video/$(date +%F --date "Yesterday")"*
```

This, at least, is guaranteed not to delete files outside of the target directory.

A safer approach here would be to do a staged cleanup. Then if something goes wrong you have some time to notice.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
cd /media/jmartin/Cams/video
if [ -d yesterday ]; then
  find yesterday -type f -delete
else
  mkdir yesterday
fi
mv "$(date +%F --date "Yesterday") "* yesterday/
```